# Django: Fetch next set of queries from Django database for async loading

Tags: mysql, django, django-views, django-queryset, django-orm

If for instance, my Django table has hundreds of rows and initially, in a view, I fetch first 10 records in the following format to be displayed on a webpage.

```
def fetchtExperts(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        experts = Experts.objects.exclude(client_assigned=None).values('id', 'name', 'age').order_by('qualification')[:10]

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'experts': experts})
```

If these 10 records are displayed on page 1, I want the next 10 records to be displayed when the user clicks on page 2. How do I fetch the next 10 records starting from the record succeeding the last fetched record? Do I send page 1's last record's ID to the view so that I could fetch the next 10 records accordingly or is there some better approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django provide [Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/pagination/) tool for such kind of problems. Change your view:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def fetchtExperts(request):
    experts = Experts.objects.exclude(client_assigned=None).values('id', 'name', 'age').order_by('qualification')
    paginator = Paginator(experts, 10) # Show 10 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    experts = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'experts': experts})
```

With this method you need to pass page number as GET argument: `http://mypage.com/view?page=1`

Comment: I tried this but I'm not able to iterate through objects in the template. I'm able to view the objects using `{{ experts.object_list }}`. I am able to send the page number through `GET` as you mentioned but I am missing something. I checked the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view  and it is similar to your answer, the iteration through Querset in the template is also normal but I'm not able to emulate the results.

Comment: No error, i just cant iterate. It's not of the Queryset data-type. If I print `experts` just before `render` (I've used your code) I get `<Page 2 of 2>` But if I print `experts.object_list` I can see the list of all the objects like this `[{'id': 28, 'name': 'q8', 'age': 20}, {'id': 29, 'name': 'asdasd', 'age': 26]`

Comment: @hulkinBrain how do you iterate?

Comment: Like this `{% for expert in experts %} {{ expert.name }} {% endfor %}`

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, I just had to pass `paginator.page(page)`  as context instead of `experts` as it is. Thanks for the answer! Cheers

Comment: Feel free to mention this in your answer mate :D